# Java EchoTCPServer - Send to all clients

Tags: java, tcp

Here's my code:

SERVER:

```
package server;

public class Main {
    public static void main(String args[]) {
        new EchoServer(9000);
    }
}
```

+

```
package server;

import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.io.PrintWriter;
import java.net.ServerSocket;
import java.net.Socket;

public class EchoServer {
    private ServerSocket server;

    public EchoServer(int port) {
        try {
            server = new ServerSocket(port);

            while (true) {
                Socket socket = server.accept();

                BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(socket.getInputStream()));
                PrintWriter out = new PrintWriter(socket.getOutputStream(), true);

                out.println(in.readLine() + " | MOD");

                socket.close();
            }
        } catch(Exception err) {
            err.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

CLIENT:

```
package client;

import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.io.PrintWriter;
import java.net.Socket;

public class Main {
    public static void main(String args[]) {
        try {
            while (true) {
                Socket socket = new Socket("localhost", 9000);

                BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(socket.getInputStream()));
                PrintWriter out = new PrintWriter(socket.getOutputStream(), true);

                BufferedReader input = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));

                out.println(input.readLine());

                System.out.println(in.readLine());

                socket.close();
            }
        } catch (Exception err) {
            System.out.println(err);
        }
    }
}
```

It works all as it should, except that I want when the server sends the "message" + " | MOD" to the client, I want the server to send that to all clients, how can I do that?

I am new to Java, but not to coding so please help me if I've done some wrong stuff that can be done easier or better.

Please help.

Thanks alot.

Answer (score 1):

What you can do is save the client sockets in an array, and then use a for loop to send to each socket.

First, declare your clientSocket array; note that 5 is just an arbitrary size used for testing. Also, declare a counter int.

```
public Socket clientSocket[] = new Socket[5];
public int intLastSocket = 0;

// this should be placed where you're waiting to accept connections
while (true) {
    printTCP("Ready to accept welcome socket");

    clientSocket[intLastSocket] = welcomeSocket.accept();

    intLastSocket++;
}

// on the server, call this to send. s is a reference to the server object
public void sendToAllTCP(TCPServer s, String message) {
    for (Socket z : s.clientSocket) {
        if (z != null) {
            PrintStream outToClient = null;
            try {
                outToClient = new PrintStream(z.getOutputStream());
                outToClient.println(message);
            } catch (IOException e) {
                TCPServer.printTCP("Caught an IO exception trying "
                        + "to send to TCP connections");
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

IN YOUR CODE:

package com.murplyx.server;

```
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.io.PrintWriter;
import java.net.ServerSocket;
import java.net.Socket;

public class EchoServer {
    private ServerSocket server;
    // use the clientSocket Array to save each new connection
    public Socket clientSocket[] = new Socket[5];

    public EchoServer(int port) {
        try {
            server = new ServerSocket(port);

            // this should be placed where you're waiting to accept connections
            while (true) {
                System.out.println("Ready to accept welcome socket");

                clientSocket[intLastSocket] = server.accept();

                intLastSocket++;

                //send your message here, note that putting
                //it here will send it each time u add a new connection
                sendToAllTCP(/*the message you want to send */);
            }
        } catch(Exception err) {
            err.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    public void sendToAllTCP(String message) {
        // this is an enchanced for loop, i don't know if it's in other languages
        // but in java it's supposed to let you loop through 
        //each object in any iterable list
        // such as array, arraylist, linkedlist, etc
        for (Socket z : clientSocket) {
            if (z != null) {
                //basically this chunk of code declares output and input streams 
                //for each socket in your array of saved sockets
                PrintStream outToClient = null;
                try {
                    outToClient = new PrintStream(z.getOutputStream());
                    outToClient.println(message);
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    System.out.println("Caught an IO exception trying "
                            + "to send to TCP connections");
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Depending on when you want to send your message, you can use the console and `sys.in` to send it. For example, if you read a line from `sys.in` and it `.equals("sendMsg")`, then you can call `sendToAllTCP(yourmessage)`

Comment: Can you please put this inside my code? It will be much easier to understand then.

Comment: If you want to send back a modified version of a string you took in, I would recommend creating a listener thread. The .accept() method is blocking, so if I recall correctly, you shouldn't be able to take in any input from the connected client.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27927279/java-tcp-echo-server-broadcast Can you please check that out?

Answer (score 0):

You should take a look at multiThreaded chat Server. Each client wich connects gets it's own thread.

Here is the perfect answer to your question:

[multithread client-server chat, using sockets](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10961683/multithread-client-server-chat-using-sockets)

Good luck mate!